# Want to create regular expression that a matches a string after particular pattern

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression which matches any string after particular pattern. For example

**What is the price of tata consultancy services**

I tried by following expression that matches whole string but I want to match only 'tata consultancy services'

```
/^(what is the price of)(\s*[a-zA-Z ]*)/ig
```

Comment: Your value [is in Group 2](https://regex101.com/r/qAS0Ta/1). Just access it and there is all there is to  it. What is your programming language? JS?

Comment: Yes my value is group 2 but I donot want to extract only tata consulatancy service

Comment: Can you have then in a single group `/^(what is the price of\s+[a-zA-Z ]*)/ig`.

Comment: I am not using any programming language but using LUIS for creating bots and I am trying to use their Regex feature

Comment: Yes I tried /^(what is the price of\s+[a-zA-Z ]*)/ig this one also

Comment: Try `(?<=^What is the price of )[a-zA-Z ]*`, just to make sure the lookbehinds are supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

With the i, why A-Z? And why capture the Prefix, if only interested in the 2nd part:

```
/^what is the price of \s*([a-z ]*)/ig
```

Maybe the string is followed by something, like a question mark?

```
/^what is the price of \s*([a-z ]*).*/ig
```

And you normally don't want Text with leading white space.